# Can you link a C++ Linux-targeted application to an Objective-C static library?

Tags: c++, objective-c, linux, static-libraries, apple-push-notifications

I've seen plenty of information on how to link an Objective-C application to C++ libraries, but can you do the other way around?

My partners and I have been working on an iPhone App using entirely Objective-C. Half way through the project, we decide to add a new feature to it. This feature will require Push Notifications, so we need to write the server-side application that will be running on a Linux box. This server app needs access to some (most, actually) of the code written in Objective-C. I figure we have two choices: re-write the whole thing in C/C++ or re-compile the Objective-C code on Linux. As rewriting would take too long, I'd like to take the second route.

I managed to use GCC and GNUstep to compile the Objective-C classes we'll need for the linux server app into a static library. I'd like to write the actual server app in C++, but I need to link that app to the Objective-C library. Can it be done? How?

If not, can anyone give me an idea of how to go about this?

Comment: I think you basically need to put the call into `.m` file and call whatever c functions you defined there?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker maybe you meant `.mm`? Either way, what you're saying is that all my source files for the server-side linux app will have to be compiled by the GCC Objective-C frontend? Can't I name my files `something.cpp` and link them to the Objective-C library (`-lMyObjCLib`)?

Comment: `.m` should do. And no, I think you can call plain `c` function defined in `.m` file from `.c` or `.cc` (or `.cpp`) file. It's just the interfacing part that should be `.m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc on your Linux box should be capable to compile Objective-C together with standard foundation classes like `NSString` or `NSArray`. You may need to `apt-get` the front-end to gcc. Or even better use LLVM.

As long as you don't use Apple libraries in your shared code you should be fine to compile it on Linux.

You will have to wrap your Objective-C functionality into C functions if you want to call them from your C or C++ application. I have provided some guidance on it in my answer to this SO question: [is there any way to use Objective-C library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945028).

**EDIT**: *(to answer comment's questions)*

The wrapper function have to be **.m** files and be compiled with Objective-C compiler as it will still contain Objective-C code and just expose plain **.C** functions. It's just the same as **C API** wrapper for C++ code still needs to be a C++ code - just having `extern "C"` functions defined. In Objective-C, you need **no** `extern "C"` as Objective-C is still C - the same linkage, etc.

You can use the resultant library with simple `-l` flag in GCC-compliant compilers.

By Apple libraries, I mean something more than `NSFoundation.h` - the specific iPhone libraries - like *CocoaTouch*.

`NSFoundation.h` is definitely provided by your Objective-C package / GNUStep.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem to be exactly what I need. But I think I need a few more details. The source files containing the implementation of the wrapper functions would have to be **.m**, right? And compiled by GCC/Linux as an Objective-C static library? Then how would my C/C++ application link to that lib? A normal `-l` linker option? Also, by "Apple libraries" do you mean **Foundation.h** and such? Thank you again, I was a bit lost, but I'm starting to see how this is done.

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho - just updated my answer to reflect your questions. Don't forget to upvote & accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: Great! I'll try that, makes a lot of sense to me so it should work. Thank you so much.